# How to store in a a textValue

Tags: java

Im working on a big project that acts like excel.I have a class that makes a table, a class that works as the client, a value class, NumberValue class, textValue class, a realNumber class. The realNumberValue class extends the NumberValue Class and the NumberValue class and the TextValue Class extends the Value CLass. (Inheritance) I need to know how to put in a string field, a constructor that assigns the parameter to the field in this TextValue Class.Please I really need Help.

This is the code that I have so far, its not much:

```
public class TextValue extends Value {
    public String toString(){
        return;
    }
    public boolean isText() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check list of answers related learning java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-java-books-websites-etc

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TextValue extends Value {
    String field;
    public TextValue(String field){
          this.field = field;
    }
    //do some more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's depend on the Value class, if its abstract and haven't any fields, then all your work will be on the child classes, just add member variables and initialize it if you want in the constructor.

```
public class TextValue extends Value {
    public TextValue(final String text) {
       this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return text;
    }
    public boolean isText() {
        return !text.isEmpty();  // it depend on what you want to do
    }

    private final String text;
}
```

but if the Value need some value in constructor you should pass it from the child class:

```
public class TextValue extends Value {
    public TextValue(final String valueClassParam, final String text) {
       super(valueClassParam);
       this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return text;
    }
    public boolean isText() {
        return !text.isEmpty();  // it depend on what you want to do
    }

    private final String text;
}
```

here we initialize the parent class with valueClassParam.